# WebStorm 2016.3 + Electron: Unresolved function or method

Tags: javascript, github, ecmascript-6, webstorm, electron

I am playing around with Electron and WebStorm as part of a project preparation and I am struggling with different problems. Therefore I want to start simple by creating very basic stuff and working my way up.

So I have a very simple project setup in WebStorm and my first Electron app is running. But WebStorm keeps saying that it cannot resolve function names.

[image]

Electron and electron-prebuilt are added to the `package.json` and Node.js coding assistance is enabled. Therefore `require('electron')` is recognised correctly.

I saw the blog entry by JetBrains on how to start with Electron in WebStorm and found also another similar answer here on StackOverflow.

[JetBrains' blog entry](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/10/working-with-reactjs-in-webstorm-coding-assistance/)

[StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846392/how-to-integrate-electron-to-webstorm-having-no-module-is-not-installed-hint)

It is said, that one should add `github-electron` to the JavaScript library from the communitie-stubs repositories. But these seems outdated, as there is no github-electron anymore and all other electron entries are ambiguous.

[image]

[image]

So my question is: How to setup WebStorm for plain JS ES6 correctly, beginning by eliminating the "unresolved" messages?

Answer (score 7):

So, after digging into the topic more and more and climbing the steep learning curve, I finally found the answer by myself.

Here we go:

1. Go to WebStorm's **Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / TypeScript**
2. Make sure **Use TypeScript Service** is enabled

[image]

3. Open up WebStorm's Terminal panel (as it will automatically point to your project's working directory) and install the type definitions for TypeScript via NPM:

   [image]

   `npm install @types/electron`

   You don't need to use the `--save` / `--save-dev` tags, as the types are needed solely for WebStorm's code assistance and have no impact on your project.

   [image]

   You'll get a new entry inside your *node_modules* folder containing the type definitions.

   [image]

   And that's it. WebStorm does not show any *unresolved function or method messages* for this particular module anymore.

   [image]

   This works for theoretically every other module, as long as there are type definitions available. But chances are good, as there are a lot of them. Way more than what WebStorm's JavaScript library download functionality offers.

Have a nice day, everyone!

Martin

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked for me. But, with Webstorm 2016.3 there had so many options in TypeScript Community Stubs. But it 2016.3.3 I can't find those except 3 suggestions. What about that?

Comment: One more thing I'd like to mention, I had to enable the <project>/node_modules from the Language & Frameworks > Javascript > Libraries to get the messages disappeared.

Comment: @ssi-anik, that's a bug because the community repo restructured their files. They're fixing it for the next release (2017.1.1) but no decision if they're pushing the change back to 2016.3/2 or not. In the meantime you can do it manually:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000140384/comments/115000165650

Answer (score 0):

install the electron library. Since the github-electron has renamed to electron.